# PHP - Best way of taking percentage of transaction

Tags: php, paypal, payment-gateway, payment, stripe-payments

I'm building a website in PHP where users place bids on items. Once bidding has ended, a payment needs to be paid from the winning bidder to the listing owner. But, as the website owner, I also want to take a small percentage - say 5%.

So the process would be the winning bidder pays £100 to the listing owner, and I take 5% as that transaction takes place.

What's the best way of doing this?

I've read about PayPal MassPay, but I'm not sure whether it's what I need or not.

I'm in the UK too, not US - if that effects anything.

Comment: For this, I'd build a non-web prototype to see if the product you mention would be suitable. I should think if you use their test server, you can play around with different payments without any money actually needing to be involved.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Stripe Connect](https://stripe.com/docs/connect) to do this if you're in the UK. You would ask your users to connect their Stripe account to your Connect Application first. You would get some data back, especially a `publishable_key` and an `access_token` which you would store on your end.

The you would use those this way:

- On the front-end along with Stripe.js or Stripe Checkout you need to use the `publishable_key` you got from the connected user when going through the Connect flow. You should *not* use your API key.
- Once you get a card token you send it to your server where you will create a charge. There, you should *not* set your API key but you should pass the `access_token` of the connected user as a second parameter to the Create Charge API. You can see some example code in the [documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/collecting-fees) showing how to collect fees.

This would automatically deposit the funds in the connected user's Stripe account minus the Stripe fee and the `application_fee` you chose. The fee would need to be a specific amount and not a percentage but you can calculate this on your end when creating the charge.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question, the solution would be as following:

1. Seller adds a listing on your website.
2. Bidding starts.
3. Buyer bids and win. E.g. for $10
4. Buyer [pays using PayPal](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/web/accept-paypal-payment/) to your website, where money goes to your account (website owner).
5. You cut 5% of it, ($0.50) and do a [Payout](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/direct/payouts-overview/) to seller's PayPal account of $9.50.

Optionally/Generally, website owners hold the money till the end of the month, and pay the seller the final amount, (if he is selling more than one thing, or he is a big merchant.)

However, the flow should help you setup a website based on your preferences. Many websites like eBay, Free lancing, apply the similar flow.

As a PayPal Employee, I would recommend using [PayPal PHP SDK](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK) for developing. All the instructions are provided [here](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/wiki) and [here](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/)

Comment: Can Payouts be sent in the UK though via PayPal?

Comment: Payouts is available to send from the UK and from the US, to domestic and cross-border recipients….  Sender account pays the fee, fee depends on what country they are sending from.  It is just the nice developer.paypal.com self-service onboarding flow is for US only.

The non-US user needs to contact their local PayPal Customer Service group and request access to Payouts or Mass Payments.  Once they have that approval, they can then can create an App in My Apps on developer.paypal.com, get credentials and us the Payouts API.